# How to factor polynomials like $x^4-x^2-1$ and $x^4-2x^2-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

When it comes to polynomials whose zeros are $n^{th}$ roots of irrational quadratic integers (mainly units), like the above examples, what is the general method in determining the degree of each irreducible factor in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]$? All outside a list of finitely many primes $p$ of course. I chose these two specific ones for two reasons;

1). The Galois group of the polynomials $f(X)=X^4-X^2-1$ and $g(X)=X^4-2X^2-1$ are not abelian, unlike the $h(X)=X^4-4X^2+1$ whose roots are

$$\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{3}}=\pm\frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

alluding to quadratic reciprocity. And adjoining a root of $f$ or $g$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{n})$.

2) I had tried doing so without success and forgot until I came back, after learning some reciprocity, and was able to remember on the off chance a way to do so for these two specific cases.

For an example computation, the zeros of $f(X)$ are

$$\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, \pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}.$$

Determining the action of the map $T_{p}: r \mapsto r^{p} \pmod{p}$ for $$r \in \left\{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, -\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}, -\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right\}$$ an ordered set can be worked with by knowing properties of the quartic residue symbol 
$$\Big[\frac{5}{p}\Big]_{4}=5^{\frac{p-1}{4}} \pmod{p}$$
and that
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}=\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}}=\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}.$$

From there, it becomes a lot easier to factor in because the action of $T_{p}$ is straightforward with the minimal polynomial of $\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$, and the action is relatively accessible with the residue symbol.

The same goes for determining the action of $T_{p}$ for $g(X)$ by considering quartic residue symbol $\left[\dfrac{2}{p}\right]_{4}$ and $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}$.

But this approach feels too ad hoc, and doesn't say anything about how to factor anything like, for example, $\displaystyle f(X^n)$ in general. What kind of tools are used to find how $h(X^{3})$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]$? $h(X^{\frac{3}{2}})$?

Also, phrased using the language of fields, this raises the question of when the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $q$ an irrational square-free quadratic integer

Comment: This question is vague. What do you mean by "compute"? Compute for a given $p$? Compute it quickly? Give a "formula" for all $p$? If so, what types of formulae are allowed, and why do you think they exist? What is the analog (to you) of what the answer should look like when taking an $n$th root of a rational integer? For example, take a cube root of $2$. Are you looking for an answer that says: $x^3 - 2$ has $3$ roots modulo $p$ if $p = x^2 + 27 y^2$? Or the more tautological $x^3 - 2$ has $3$ roots modulo $p$ if $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $2$ is a cube mod $p$. What is your answer for $x^5 - 2$?

Comment: @Gordon Forgot that compute has its own precise definition in mathematics. Basically the goal is to get the formulation $p=x^2+27y^2$, but not as precise. An expression as a product of characters $\Big[\frac{\pi}{2}\Big]_{3} \cdot \chi_{3}(\pi)=1$ being the criteria for $x^3-2$ having 3 roots in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is what I think I want, where $\pi$ an Eisenstein prime with norm $p$.  For the example of $x^3-2$ you used, I did not know what I wanted until I had gotten it, and even then It had taken me a moment.

Comment: @Gordon I assume $x^5-2$ factors mod p based on some character mod 10 in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{5})$? That's not something I want to learn. Also, I don't want to learn necessarily a formula, but more along the lines of learning to build the tools that are used to make them!

Comment: Even assuming "That's not something I want to learn" in your previous comment is a typo, your response is still vague, and it's hard to imagine a more appropriate response than "learn some class field theory."

Answer (score 1):

Recall that any irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ factors into linear factors in $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. As such you can compute $\gcd(p(x), x^{p^k}-x)$ for all highest-prime-power $k\le n$. We do this for all of them as your polynomial may not be irreducible (so it may be a product of irreducible factors, but we know all such factors have degree at most $n$). So we compute for $k=q^j$ for prime powers $q^j\le n$ and so that $j$ is maximal (since $j<j'\implies q^{j'}|q^j$). Then this gives you all possible common factors with each of the $x^{p^{q^j}}-x$ which generate all possible roots for $p(x)$. This can be automated by programming a computer to run the Euclidean algorithm on each of the polynomials and spitting out the result.